# How to connect two SalesForce instances

Tags: integration

I want to integrate two seperate Salesforce orgs, this is the following workflow:

1. Create a case in Salesforce A. this case will have to meet a set of criteria.and there is button to send data to salesforce B, if we click the button, then..
2. Send this case over to Salesforce B.
3. When the case is received by Salesforce B, you would like the case to be created As A SA Potential. With some/all data from Salesforce A.
4. then, update case status in salesforce A to be closed when status SA Potential is Submit in salesforce B.

I have no idea where should i start, do you guys have any idea or sample code of it? what kind of process that i should make?

thankyou for your help

Comment: Hi. As per the community expectations, you need to show that you have done some research and tried to resolve this for yourself if you want to avoid your question being closed without answer.

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to connect two Salesforce instances, depending on the specific use case and requirements. For your use case, API-based integration suits you. Salesforce provides a set of rest APIs which can be used to integrate two different orgs.
[Salesforce REST API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/intro_rest.htm)
Also, you can find many blogs on how to use salesforce APIs.

https://www.gosquared.com/blog/salesforce-rest-api-integration
https://www.forcetalks.com/blog/integrating-one-salesforce-org-to-another-salesforce-org-using-rest-api/